# How to prevent Webdriver from breaking after first few loops?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, webdriver

I've written a script to extract information from a webpage. I was expecting that the webdriver will go through the list of 50+ URLs extract all the information.

But it fails just after few iterations and stop working. It throws error WebDriver Exception.
I have restarted the webdriver few times and have added sleep(7) between each iteration and still it randomly stops working after first few iterations.

I have a deadline on this project please help.

```
for product_URL in all_profile_url:
    wd.get(product_URL)
    time.sleep(7)
    
    page_source = BeautifulSoup(wd.page_source, "html.parser")

    info_div = page_source.find('div', class_='ProductInfoCard__Breadcrumb-sc-113r60q-4 cfIqZP')

    info_block = info_div.find_all('a')
    try:
        info_category = info_block[1].get_text().strip()
    except IndexError:
        info_category ="Null"
    
    try:
        info_sub_category = info_block[2].get_text().strip()
    except IndexError:
        info_sub_category='Null'
    
    try:
        info_product_name = info_div.find_all('span')[0].get_text().strip()
    except IndexError:
        info_product_name='null'
    

    # Extract Brand name
    info_div_1 = page_source.find('div', class_='ProductInfoCard__BrandContainer-sc-113r60q-9 exyKqL')
    try:
        info_brand = info_div_1.find_all('a')[0].get_text().strip()
    except IndexError:
        info_brand='null'
    

    # Extract details for rest of the page
    info_div_2 = page_source.find('div', class_='ProductDetails__RemoveMaxHeight-sc-z5f4ag-3 fOPLcr')
    info_block_2 = info_div_2.find_all('div', class_='ProductAttribute__ProductAttributesDescription-sc-dyoysr-2 lnLDYa')
    try:
        info_shelf_life = info_block_2[0].get_text().strip()
    except IndexError:
        info_shelf_life = 'null'
    
    try:
        info_country_of_origin = info_block_2[3].get_text().strip()
    except IndexError:
        info_country_of_origin='null'
    
    try:
        info_weight = info_block_2[9].get_text().strip()
    except IndexError:
        info_weight ='null'
    
    try:
        info_expiry_date = info_block_2[7].get_text().strip()
    except IndexError:
        info_expiry_date='null'
    # Extract MRP and price
    # Extract MRP and price
    info_div_3 = page_source.find('div', class_='ProductVariants__VariantCard-sc-1unev4j-3 bEuNss')
    info_block_3 = info_div_3.find_all('div', class_='ProductVariants__PriceContainer-sc-1unev4j-9 jjiIua')
    info_price_raw = info_block_3[0].get_text().strip()
    info_price = info_block_3[0].get_text().strip()[1:3]
    info_MRP = info_price_raw[-2:]
    wd.back()
    time.sleep(wait_time)
```

```
Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\NIHARIKA\Documents\Development python\htmlscripts\blinkit scrapper.ipynb Cell 12' in <cell line: 1>()
     10 time.sleep(wait_time)
     11 #wd.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)')
     12 #time.sleep(wait_time)
---> 13 page_source = BeautifulSoup(wd.page_source, "html.parser")
     15 info_div = page_source.find('div', class_='ProductInfoCard__Breadcrumb-sc-113r60q-4 cfIqZP')
     17 info_block = info_div.find_all('a')

File c:\Users\NIHARIKA\miniconda3\envs\webscraping\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py:932, in WebDriver.page_source(self)
    922 @property
    923 def page_source(self) -> str:
    924     """
    925     Gets the source of the current page.
    926 
   (...)
    930             driver.page_source
    931     """
--> 932     return self.execute(Command.GET_PAGE_SOURCE)['value']

File c:\Users\NIHARIKA\miniconda3\envs\webscraping\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py:430, in WebDriver.execute(self, driver_command, params)
    428 response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    429 if response:
--> 430     self.error_handler.check_response(response)
...
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x75CDFA29+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77467A9E+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77467A6E+238]
    (No symbol) [0x00000000]
```

EDIT: I also added wd.back() in the end of for loop. Still stops but at a different URL. Above error is when I manually input URLs without for loop
**What can be done, to get past such nuisance?**

Comment: What is exact Exception?

Comment: It shows error on wd.get(product_url) command. nothing else shown

Comment: Could you post the traceback?

Comment: @dosas done, edited above

Answer (score 0):

The error is within the line:

```
----> 1 wd.get(all_profile_url[2])
```

Presumably you have got all the urls stored in the list `all_profile_url`.

So I don't see any error in code trial within the question:

```
for product_URL in all_profile_url:
    wd.get(product_URL)
```

---

Incase you want to iterate the list using an `index` you can use the following alternative code block:

```
for i in range(len(all_profile_url)):
    wd.get(all_profile_url[i])
```

Comment: I'm stuck on this problem for past 4 hours. Please bear with me. I'll edit the error code after rerunning code. The above error is for a different code without for loop. I'll edit in 5 mins. I'm quite exhausted and desperate rn given the client's first project with me. So just bear with me. Thanks  @undetected Selenium

Comment: I have edited the error message above.

Comment: No other web driver command is running once I get this error. I have to restart the webdriver. When does this happen ?